# Vlookup to match the SUBSET of a cell with contains

Tags: excel

I would like to do a vlookup,but i would like it to match the SUBSET of a cell. is this possible?

For example, I have a value in SHEET1 cell A2 as `Alcatel 7705 SAR-8 FAN v1` and i have a value in another SHEET2 cell B2 as `7705 SAR-8 FAN v1`, i want to match and put the value of SHEET2 cell B2 in sheet1 and match `7705 SAR-8 FAN v1`.

I am trying to use wildcard in vlookup as

```
=VLOOKUP("*"& A2 &"*",'SHEET2'!B:B,1,FALSE)
```

but it is not working. please help.

Comment: Look into [`Index/Match`](http://www.randomwok.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match/), you can use a wildcard in `Match()`.

Comment: @Kyle Vlookups absolutely do support wildcards (for me at least): http://imgur.com/8RVDIjh.png

Comment: @Mikegrann good to know. Not sure why I always thought they didn't. My comment is now deleted.

Answer (score 4):

This will need to be and array formula using INDEX/MATCH:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$100,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$100,A2)),0))
```

Being an array formula one must confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: How does the `Match()` work there? I've not used Index/Match with `1`/`True` before - so is that match mean where there's a value (`TRUE`?) and that value is in Sheet2B2:B100 ?

Comment: @BruceWayne Search returns a number or an error.  A number when it finds the text string in another text string.  So we are iteration through B2:B100 and creating an array of numbers and errors.  The ISNUMBER turns the numbers into true and the errors into false.  Then the match will return the first true in the array.